# Accessing non-Kohana php files

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana

I have a Kohana application running in the web root and everything is working fine. But when I try to add a subfolder to the root with non-kohana PHP code, I can't access it. Kohana still tries to find a route for the file..

Example:

- public_html

  - application
  - modules
  - subfolder

    - index.php
    - test.html

If I try to access /subfolder, I get the following error:

Class controller_subfolder does not exist

But if I try to access /subfolder/test.html it works fine.

My .htaccess file is the default:

> ```
> # Turn on URL rewriting
> RewriteEngine On
>
> # Installation directory
> RewriteBase /
>
> # Protect hidden files from being viewed
> <Files .*>
>   Order Deny,Allow
>   Deny From All
> </Files>
>
> # Protect application and system files from being viewed
> RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
>
> # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
> RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
> ```

Comment: Can you post your bootstrap.php routes?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe apache is not configured to deliver index.php in the DirectoryIndex?

Take a look @ http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html